# React HighChart Example

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I m using React-js-highcharts, and i have done the below code, getting data  e.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
error.

Kindly help me to sort out this.

Have followed this example.

https://github.com/whawker/react-jsx-highcharts/blob/gh-pages/examples/SimpleLine/App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import {
    HighchartsChart, Chart, withHighcharts, XAxis, YAxis, Title, Subtitle, Legend, LineSeries
  } from 'react-jsx-highcharts';
import { extent as d3ArrayExtent } from 'd3-array';


const plotOptions = {
    series: {
      pointStart: 2010
    }
  };

class ProductHealth extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            data: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount()  {

        let defaultOptions = {
            method:'GET',
            headers:{
                Accept: 'application/json',
            }
        };

        fetch('http://localhost:3000/health', defaultOptions)
        .then(function(response) {
            // The response is a Response instance.
            // You parse the data into a useable format using `.json()`
            let resData = response.json();
            return resData;
          }).then(response => {
              console.log("Response",response);
              this.processResponseData(response);
        }).catch(function(error){ console.log(error) })
    }

    processResponseData = (response) => {
        let apiValues = [];
        response.forEach(element => {
            let value = [];
            element.values.forEach(item => {
                value.push(
                    [item.count]
                );
            })

            apiValues.push({
                name : element.api,
                value : value
            })
        });

        this.setState({
            data : apiValues
        });
    };



    renderLineChart() {
        return this.state.data.map((lineData, index) => {
            return (
                <LineSeries key={index} name={lineData.api} data={lineData.value} />
            )
        })  
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.data.length > 0) {
        return (

            <div>
                <HighchartsChart plotOptions={plotOptions}>
                <Chart />

                <Title>Visa Direct Data</Title>
                <Legend layout="vertical" align="right" verticalAlign="middle" />
                <XAxis>
                    <XAxis.Title>Time</XAxis.Title>
                </XAxis>
                <YAxis>
                <YAxis.Title>API Calls</YAxis.Title>
                   {this.renderLineChart()}
                </YAxis>
                </HighchartsChart>
            </div>
        ); 
        } else {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;

        }
    }
}

export default withHighcharts(ProductHealth, Highcharts);
```

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend you to try to use our official React wrapper which is also available to download through `npm`.

Here is the link to package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official

GitHub repository: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I will go through this and see if i can make it.

Comment: Hi, do you have an example with this context menu on top right with working Full Screen mode? On this example it is not working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4ded5d?file=index.js

Comment: @Vlado it does look like the stackblitz platform has blocked full screen feature when editing. After opening the demo in the new window (clicking the button above the result section), the button does work fine.

Comment: In fact I experience difficulties AFTER returning back from full screen - although I have fixed height wrapper the chart always returns to much bigger height (stretched always to 1080px by some reason - not respecting the wrapper). Unfortunately I have no time to try to reproduce in some js sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm 7 months late to this, but looks like the clue lies in

```
You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object
```

You are returning `this.state.data.map` which will return an array.

I would suggest you try

```
renderLineChart () {
  const { data } = this.state
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {data.map((lineData, index) => (
        <LineSeries key={index} name={lineData.api} data={lineData.value} />
      )}
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```